# Excel PIA returning null for a cell with a number in

Tags: .net, excel, office-pia

I have a problem in that using the following code

```
var num = sheet.Cells[row, col].Value;
```

or

```
var num = sheet.Cells[row, col].Value2;
```

will not return a value if the cell contains only a number. Am I missing something silly here? I also ought to mention that I am doing this with a csv file and office 2010.

Thanks all.

Comment: var num is declared as what? number or string? Try FormulaR1C1 to get the value

Comment: Please put this as an answer so I can accept it and give you the rep. FormulaR1C1 solved it for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var num is declared as what? number or string? Try FormulaR1C1 to get the value. Works sometimes. :)